# Changing height of fade for parallax CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to shorten my collapsing toolbar layout but when I change the height of the CollapsingToolBbarLayout to my desired new height (200dp) it, the image appears faded already on page load. I'm assuming there some way to set the height at which the image fades to go along with this but I just can't find anything helpful... thanks ahead of time

Here is the layout I'm using:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/htab_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/mountains"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="104dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleMarginTop="13dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Code from tutorial: http://blog.grafixartist.com/parallax-scrolling-tabs-design-support-library/

Answer (score 3):

It's actually not that simple because the scrim trigger is determined by a private method in `CollapsingToolbarLayout`:

```
final int getScrimTriggerOffset() {
    return 2 * ViewCompat.getMinimumHeight(this);
}
```

Trying to override it is tricky.

---

One way to do it is to just make your own scrim:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/htab_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/header"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrim"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:alpha="0" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleMarginTop="13dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

And trigger it similar to how `CollapsingToolbarLayout` does:

```
// For status bar scrim
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(0x40000000);
}
collapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrimColor(0);

final View scrim = findViewById(R.id.scrim);
AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener listener = new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        if(collapsingToolbarLayout.getHeight() + verticalOffset < ViewCompat.getMinimumHeight(collapsingToolbarLayout) * 3 / 2) {
            scrim.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(600);
        } else {
            scrim.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(600);
        }
    }
};

appBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(listener);
```

Comment: I also use this way to make animation refer to offset, although looks weird.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new attribute on the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in v24 of the design support library: `scrimVisibleHeightTrigger`.

Here is what the documentation says about it:

> Set the amount of visible height in pixels used to define when to
>   trigger a scrim visibility change. If the visible height of this view
>   is less than the given value, the scrims will be made visible,
>   otherwise they are hidden.